# Cordova camera permission is DENIED_ALWAYS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, permissions, camera

I'm building an app with Cordova/angularjs, I'm checking the camera permission like this :
 `

```
getCameraAuthorization: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getCameraAuthorizationStatus(function(status) {
                status = unifyPermissionStatus.bind(this)(status);
                if (status === this.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED) {
                    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestCameraAuthorization(function(status) {
                        deferred.resolve(unifyPermissionStatus.bind(this)(status));
                    }.bind(this), function(error) {
                        logger.error('The following error occurred: ' + error);
                        deferred.reject({ error: 1, message: error });
                    }, { externalStorage: false });
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve(status);
                }
            }.bind(this), function(error) {
                logger.error('The following error occurred: ' + error);
                deferred.reject({ error: 1, message: error });
            }, { externalStorage: false });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

`

And it used to work, but not anymore. Now the status I get is 'DENIED_ALWAYS'. It may have been since I passed the project to cordova 8.0 (my only lead here).

Anyone have an idea about what happened ?

Thanks.

Comment: Believe this just means a user denied access to the camera at some point and they/you need to manually enable it after it has been explicitly denied access (believe this is the case with desktop notifications requests from websites as well, if the user has said 'no' then you can't prompt them again at least without direct user interaction to stop someone from spamming the user with requests).

Comment: Had you find any solution ? @matth56

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case was that the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

was not added to the androidManifest.xml. So I added a plugin that add permission to the manifest in my config.xml :

```
<plugin name="cordova-custom-config" spec="../plugins-git/cordova-custom-config-5.0.2" />
```

And then :

```
<platform name="android">
    <custom-config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*" mode="merge">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    </custom-config-file>
</platform>
```